# drag & drop current element JS

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have 2 divs and 2 paragraphs. Could someone say how could I put paragraph in current div?
Example:
1paragraph --> 1div, but 1paragraph can't go to 2div.
2paragraph --> 2div, but 2paragraph can't go to 1div.

**My Code:**

```js
var dragClass, dropClass;
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="1element"></div>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="2element"></div>
<br>
<p id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="1element">This is a draggable paragraph. Drag this element into the rectangle.</p>
<p id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="2element">This is a draggable paragraph. Drag this element into the rectangle.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. It works with this one line

```
mover.assign('your-div-id') ;
```

It's okay to have multiple divs with `style="display:inline-block"`

```
const mover = {
    target      : null ,
    zMax        : 0 ,
    startX      : 0 ,
    startY      : 0 ,
    pX          : 0 ,
    pY          : 0 ,
    differenceX : 0 ,
    differenceY : 0 ,
    step        : 1 ,
    assign: function(elementId) {
        mover.target = document.getElementById(elementId) ;
        mover.target.addEventListener('mousedown',mover.moveStart,{once:false}) ;
        mover.target.addEventListener('mouseleave',mover.moved,{once:false}) ;
    } ,
    setCurrentPosition: function(reference) {
        let mom      = reference.parentElement ;
        let brothers = Array.from(mom.childNodes) ;
        if(brothers) {
            do{
                brother = brothers.pop() ;
                if(!brother) break ;
                if(brother.style.position) continue ;
                let styles = window.getComputedStyle(brother);
                let marginTop  = parseInt(styles['margin-left'],10) ;
                let marginLeft = parseInt(styles['margin-top'],10) ; ;
                brother.style.left = (brother.offsetLeft-marginLeft) + 'px' ;
                brother.style.top  = (brother.offsetTop-marginTop) + 'px' ;
                brother.style.position = 'absolute' ;
            }while(true) ;
        }
    } ,
    moveStart: function(event) {
        mover.setCurrentPosition(this) ;
        mover.zMax += mover.step ;
        mover.target.style.zIndex = mover.zMax ;
        mover.startX = this.offsetLeft  ;
        mover.startY = this.offsetTop ;
        mover.pX = event.pageX ;
        mover.pY = event.pageY ;
        mover.target.addEventListener('mousemove',mover.moving,{once:true}) ;
        mover.target.addEventListener('mouseup',mover.moved,{once:true}) ;
    } ,
    moving: function(event) {
        mover.differenceX = event.pageX - mover.pX 　;
        mover.differenceY = event.pageY - mover.pY　;
        mover.target.style.position = 'absolute' ;
        mover.target.style.left = mover.startX + mover.differenceX + 'px' ;
        mover.target.style.top  = mover.startY + mover.differenceY + 'px' ;
        mover.target.addEventListener('mousemove',mover.moving,{once:true}) ;
    } ,
    moved: function() {
        mover.target.removeEventListener('mousemove',mover.moving,{once:true}) ;
    } ,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

Just set unique id of `div` and `p` tag.

```js
var dragClass, dropClass;
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
#div1 ,#div2{
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="1element"></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="2element"></div>
<br>
<p id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="1element">This is a draggable paragraph. Drag this element into the rectangle.</p>
<p id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="2element">This is a draggable paragraph. Drag this element into the rectangle.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to do it, but how should I do the unique id of div and p

Comment: @user670290 Please check the answer again in that I give a unique Id of div and p

Comment: 1. You didn't.
2. I will answer on my question now

Comment: @user670290 Can you please tell me what's different between your output and my output?

Comment: In your example you can put in 1div 1paragraph and 2paragraph and in my example - no. In my example you can only put par1 in div1 and par2 in div2

Comment: @user670290 Ok.. got it

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question is:

```js
var dragClass, dropClass;


function allowDrop(ev) {
  dropClass = event.target.classList;
      if(`${dropClass}` === `${dragClass}`) {
        ev.preventDefault();
      } else {}
}

function drag(ev) {
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
   dragClass = event.target.classList;
   
}

function drop(ev) {
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
#div2 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="boat"></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="house"></div>
<br>
<p id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="boat">This is a draggable paragraph. Drag this element into the rectangle.</p>
<p id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" class="house">This is a draggable paragraph. Drag this element into the rectangle.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```