# Element that calls the function JS

Tags: javascript, element

Could someone say how to select and element that called current function?

```
function Myfunc() {
  element.style.padding = '16px';
}
```

//---

```
<button onclick="Myfunc()">Click Me!</button>
```

I ask how to do it without giving an id or class to the element, and without:

`function Myfunc(this) { }`

Comment: you can just use `this` inside `Myfunc()` without specifying it as a function param. swap `element.style.padding = '16px';` for `this.style.padding = '16px';`

Comment: But I asked to do it *without* using this

Comment: Just curious, what is your aversion to using `this` or `id`?

Comment: If you don't know why then you can just go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822050/drag-drop-current-element-js and try solving it 'with' this...

Comment: No, you asked how to do it without setting a parameter called `this`

Comment: Ahhh...
I asked you to solve it with 'this' in the post stackoverflow.com/questions/65822050/…
and after you would understand it's unreal - you would understand why I need without this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly pass the element as the argument of the function, you can refer to the `event` object, or you can inline the code (this last one is not a good option but it works nonetheless):

```js
function clickFunc1(element) {
  element.style.padding = '16px'
}

function clickFunc2() {
  event.target.style.padding = '16px'
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickFunc1(this)">ClickMe 1</button>
<button onclick="clickFunc2()">ClickMe 2</button>
<button onclick="this.style.padding = '16px'">ClickMe 3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.style.padding`:

```js
function Myfunc(element) {
  element.style.padding = '16px';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Myfunc(this)">Click Me!</button>
<button onclick="Myfunc(this)">Click Me 2!</button>
<button onclick="this.style.padding = '16px'">Click Me Without function!</button>
```

Comment: "and with out function Myfunc(this) { }" - from the question

Comment: @evolutionxbox Updated answer. Use inline code. But keep in mind that it makes code less readable and harder to maintain

Comment: Definitely agree. I think the OP needs to be aware of that

Comment: @evolutionxbox oh, you are not OP :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```js
function Myfunc(element) {
element.style.padding = '16px';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Myfunc(this)">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: "and with out function Myfunc(this) { }" - from the question.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

```js
function foo(target){
  target.style.padding = '16px';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="foo(this)">Click me!</button>
```

### Method 2 (Better)

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  const element = event.target;
  element.style.padding  = '16px';
});
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `event`.

```
<button onclick="Myfunc(event)">Click Me!</button>
```

Then `e.target` is you clicked element.

```
function Myfunc(e) {
  e.target.style.padding = '16px';
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLfgd3h0/)